# Can't login to ECR using VPC endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-ecr

**SDK version number**
`aws-cli/1.18.147 Python/2.7.18 Linux/4.14.203-156.332.amzn2.x86_64 botocore/1.18.6`

**Platform/OS/Hardware/Device**
`Amazon Linux 2`

**Describe the bug**
Can't login to ECR using VPC endpoint.
I created VPC Endpoints like [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints.html#ecr-setting-up-vpc-create) for each service name with the default policies:

```
com.amazonaws.us-east-1.ecr.api
com.amazonaws.us-east-1.ecr.dkr
com.amazonaws.us-east-1.s3
```

I run successfully:

```sh
aws --region us-east-1 ecr get-login-password
aws --region us-east-1 ecr get-login --no-include-email | bash # this runs docker login successfully
aws --region us-east-1 ecr create-repository --repository-name test/alpine2 --endpoint-url https://api.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com

## using curl - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/Registries.html#registry_auth
TOKEN=$(aws --region us-east-1 ecr get-authorization-token --output text --query 'authorizationData[].authorizationToken')
curl -i -H "Authorization: Basic $TOKEN" https://%ACCOUNT_ID%.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v2/test/alpine2/tags/list
```

But if I try to login to ECR using VPC endpoint I can't.

```sh
docker login -u AWS -p $(aws --region us-east-1 ecr get-login-password) api.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
Error response from daemon: login attempt to https://api.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v2/ failed with status: 403 Forbidden

# using curl
curl -i -H "Authorization: Basic $TOKEN" https://api.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v2/test/alpine2/tags/list 
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
x-amzn-RequestId: f7c5f001-ce49-4cb9-ae9a-8301701db80d
Date: Tue, 1 Dec 2020 13:53:07 GMT
Content-Length: 7402

<IncompleteSignatureException>
  <Message>'%LONG_TOKEN_FROM_PREVIOUS_COMMAND%' not a valid key=value pair (missing equal-sign) in Authorization header: 'Basic %LONG_TOKEN_FROM_PREVIOUS_COMMAND%'.</Message>
```

**Additional info**
I run EC2 instance in private VPC. I can successfully push image to ECR using its external name.
It means that I have perms to work with ECR. The problem is in VPC endpoint, may be.
Please, help.

Answer (score 0):

### Step1

```
#upgrade your cli its too old (to v2)
pip2 install --upgrade awscli
```

### Step2

```
#login
aws ecr get-login-password --region <region> --endpoint-url https://api.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin <account_number>.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com
```